# VBScript to send emails not working, error code 0x80040217?

Tags: email, vbscript, smtp, google-apps

I have the following VB script that works fine when sending an email from a gmail account. However, I'd like to send emails from a corporate account that uses a google apps account. I'm not sure if I should chance the SMTP server in this code, if so; what should it be?

```
Const cdoSendUsingPickup = 1 'Send message using the local SMTP service pickup directory. 
Const cdoSendUsingPort = 2 'Send the message using the network (SMTP over the network). 

Const cdoAnonymous = 0 'Do not authenticate
Const cdoBasic = 1 'basic (clear-text) authentication
Const cdoNTLM = 2 'NTLM

Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 
objMessage.Subject = "This is a test!" 
objMessage.From = "dummy1@somecorp.com" 
objMessage.To = "dummy2@somecorp.com" 
'objMessage.TextBody = "This is some sample message text.." & vbCRLF & "It was sent using SMTP authentication and SSL."
objMessage.HTMLBody = "<h1>This is some sample message in html.</h1><br/><h2>Just to test HTML elements if they're working or not.</h2>" 
'==This section provides the configuration information for the remote SMTP server.

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 

'Name or IP of Remote SMTP Server
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"

'Type of authentication, NONE, Basic (Base64 encoded), NTLM
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = cdoBasic

'Your UserID on the SMTP server
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "dummy1@somecorp.com"

'Your password on the SMTP server
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "password"

'Server port 
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465 

'Use SSL for the connection (False or True)
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True

'Connection Timeout in seconds (the maximum time CDO will try to establish a connection to the SMTP server)
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update

'==End remote SMTP server configuration section==

objMessage.Send
msgbox "Done:)"
```

Answer (score 2):

Gmail users can access their account on the official website or by using first-party or third-party apps and services instead. A first party app is for instance Google's official Gmail app for Android, while Thunderbird and the mail client app of Windows 8 are third-party apps.

Google [announced](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.de/2014/04/new-security-measures-will-affect-older.html) back in April 2014 that it would improve the sign-in security of its services and affect any application sending usernames and passwords to the company.

The company suggested to switch to OAuth 2.0 back then but did not enforce it up until now.

If you open the new [less secure](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) apps page under security settings on Google, you will notice that Google has disabled access by default.

Note: You see the page only if you are not using Google Apps or have enabled two-factor authentication for the account.

**You can flip the switch here to enable less secure applications again so that access is regained.**

[image]

Try this vbscript that works for me, on your side, and tell me if you encountered some problems or not.

```
EmailSubject = "Sending Email by CDO"
EmailBody = "This is the body of a message sent via" & vbCRLF & _
        "a CDO.Message object using SMTP authentication ,with port 465."

Const EmailFrom = "self@gmail.com"
Const EmailFromName = "My Very Own Name"
Const EmailTo = "someone@destination.com"
Const SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
Const SMTPLogon = "self@gmail.com"
Const SMTPPassword = "gMaIlPaSsWoRd"
Const SMTPSSL = True
Const SMTPPort = 465

Const cdoSendUsingPickup = 1    'Send message using local SMTP service pickup directory.
Const cdoSendUsingPort = 2  'Send the message using SMTP over TCP/IP networking.

Const cdoAnonymous = 0  ' No authentication
Const cdoBasic = 1  ' BASIC clear text authentication
Const cdoNTLM = 2   ' NTLM, Microsoft proprietary authentication

' First, create the message

Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
objMessage.Subject = EmailSubject
objMessage.From = """" & EmailFromName & """ <" & EmailFrom & ">"
objMessage.To = EmailTo
objMessage.TextBody = EmailBody

' Second, configure the server

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = SMTPServer

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = cdoBasic

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = SMTPLogon

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = SMTPPassword

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = SMTPPort

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = SMTPSSL

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update
'Now send the message!
On Error Resume Next
objMessage.Send

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox Err.Description,16,"Error Sending Mail"
Else 
    MsgBox "Mail was successfully sent !",64,"Information"
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! my script works fine when sending from gmail to another domain's mail (that uses google apps). The problem I'm having is when sending from a google app email address "someone@somedomain.com" to anything. It gives the error mentioned in my question.

Comment: I tried your script, it works fine for sending from a gmail account, but not from another domain's account.